# HTML: Displaying Select Elements as large as the browser viewport

Tags: html, css

My question is, how can I display select elements full screen (not like F11 full screen, but like having it take up the whole client browser screen space). I have to take into consideration the people who will be using my website (once it's on a .com domain), and one of the main things is I want the first three elements (logo graphic, h1 text, and h2 text) to fill up the first space, until you scroll down. How do you do that?

I tried to come up with a solution to this, so I tried changing the padding and margins around to the correct settings, but then I realized, it's only for my monitor/device. Is there any way I could make it specific for each device?

Website Link: http://noclip.ga/1/ (A friend and I are both working on different designs for it.)

PS: I have a slide in menu (from the left), will that affect the solution?

PPS: I couldn't find this post anywhere, so if you can find it, just send me a link...

EDIT: Code.

https://jsfiddle.net/052Lu6xt/2/

```
    <body>

    <nav>
        <ul><center>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/prices">Prices</a></li>
        </center></ul>
    </nav>

    <article>



    <div id="content">
    <center>
        <img src="img/logo.png" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
        <h1 style="padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px;">NØCLIP</h1>
        <h2 style="padding: 5px 20px 60px 20px;">Web development made easy.</h2>
        <table class="maintable" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; font-family: Josefin Sans; font-size: 40px; color: #C6C6C6;">

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Quick</td>
<td>Affordable</td>
<td>Easy</td>
</tr>

<tr style="font-family: Arvo; font-size: 32px;">
<td>We strive to provide you with a professional product in a timely manner.</td>
<td>Our services start at as low as $60!</td>
<td>We make it easy for you by optimizing your workload so you tell us what to do, and we do it.</td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
    </center>
    </div>
    </article>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700|Arvo|Josefin+Sans:600);

/* Made By NOCLIP */



body {
    background: rgb(5,6,6);
    width:100%;
    margin: auto;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Arvo;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ececec;
}

h3 {
    display: inline;
    font-family: Arvo;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ededed;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%0;
}

.center {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.textright {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


/* Scrolling Menu */


article {
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 30px 15%;
    background-color: rgb(5,5,6);
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

article:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: -16em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgb(32, 40, 41);
    border-right: 50px solid rgba(6, 15, 32, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -70px;
    top: 50%;
    border-width: 15px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgb(72, 97, 111);
}

nav ul {
    width: 14em;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

article, article:after, nav, nav *{
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
}

nav:hover {
    left: 0;
}

nav:hover ~ article {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}

nav:hover ~ article:after {
    left: 60%;
}

li a {
    font-family: Josefin Sans;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #0092ff;
}

li {
    padding-top: 38%;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a minute to read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask post. There are several points to first get across: the space you're trying to fill is called "**above the fold**", this may help you googling how to display elements to take up all the space above the fold - something like this: http://unbounce.com/landing-pages/how-to-design-above-the-fold-landing-page-experiences/

Comment: tl;dr, you should put a more informative title. try making the container 100% of the current viewport, or simply make two layers of page, two containers one hidden one visible switch visibility to one that uses full screen and viewport related font-size, http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the logo, h1 and h3 text within a div; this div should have a width of 100vw (viewport-width) and a height of 100vh (viewport-height).

```
#top_div {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#top_div img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: ..px //up to you
  height: auto; //keep the original width/height ratio
}

#top_div h1 {
  font-size: 10vw //play with these numbers to get the ratios right
}

#top_div h3 {
  font-size: 8vw //play with these numbers to get the ratios right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all set the html and body to 100% like:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Set main container to 100%:

```
.container{
     text-align:center;
     height:100%;
}
```

Set height of your inner 2 container of image and h1, h2 divided them 100%. I am using equal 50% of height in the following example.

```
.inner-div{
  height:50%;
  color:white;
}
```

Make your image to fit the screen size using:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

That's did the trick.
You can see the result here. https://jsfiddle.net/siddiquinoor/Lmd49qfs/